# Couldn't access ubuntu, used boot repair, cant access windows 7!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, boot-repair, testdisk

As the title says, I accidentally created a grub on my windows partition and now I can't use it. My windows install disk says that it's not compatible with my windows so that doesn't work. Then I tried this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix the test disk fix, now I am on the final screen but there is no [backup bs] option there are only [list] [rebuild BS] [repair MFT] and [Dump] so anything I can do so I can boot both windows and ubuntu?

EDIT: some googling around and I have the same screen as when you press the [backup bs] http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery as seen there. So does that mean I didn't install grub on my windows partition and running boot repair should do the trick?

EDIT2: paste.ubuntu.com/8529100/ <- if that helps..

EDIT 3: Wow okay this is freaky, I got it to work just by running boot repair again.. Now to just figure out how I can reorganise the boot so that windows is first and second is ubuntu. And for some reason it thinks my HDD also has windows now.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I'm glad you got your original problem resolved. Changing grub boot order is a different question which I'm sure you can find an answer to by searching as I know I've answered it before. In fact there are 899 results: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=grub+boot+order

Comment: Yeah, was really easy, I just have no idea how to mark this as solved. Maybe I should just delete it.

Comment: You should write up the answer to your own question as your experience may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran boot repair again, this time on the real ubuntu and that fixed my problem. Nothing special, just on the same auto repair settings.